# ASCII and UTF-8 (or UCS-2 and UTF-16) strings in the same C++ project

Tags: c++, utf-8, ascii, utf-16, ucs2

We have a project where, for historical reasons, string handling is a cacophony of encodings and representations; we definitely have places that can only handle ASCII reliably, some places probably using UTF-8, a few places at the periphery that I suspect to be using platform-specific 8-bit encoding (of course varying between our different target platforms), various places designed to take UCS-2, and maybe also some that would be happy to operate on UTF-16 - all of which are sometimes passed around as C-style strings (`char*`, `CHAR16*`) and sometimes as C++ strings (`std::string`, `std::basic_string<CHAR16>`). Of course there is very little in terms of documentation.

As a first step towards untangling this mess, I want to set up a type system using genuinely different types for the different encodings.

One idea that crossed my mind was to use e.g. `signed char` as the basis for ASCII strings and `unsigned char` for UTF-8 strings, as well as `char16_t` for UCS-2 and `short` for UTF-16 (or something along these lines), but that would mean I won't be able to directly use string literals. Also, being able to simply feed ASCII strings to functions expecting UTF-8 (but not vice versa) would be neat.

Do you have any smart suggestions for how to go about this, or maybe even working code?

The code needs to be compatible with C++11.

Please refrain from any answers along the lines of "just use UTF-8 consistently throughout", because that's pretty much my end goal anyway; rather, this is about creating a tool that I think would help me a lot to get there.

-- addendum --

I should probably have mentioned that I presume we already have issues where string encoding doesn't "line up" properly, e.g. UTF-16 strings being passed to functions that can only handle UCS-2 strings, or platform-specific 8-bit strings being passed to functions that expect ASCII strings. Just yesterday I found dedicated conversion functions carrying "ASCII" in their name that de-facto would actually convert to/from Latin-1 instead of ASCII.

Comment: `utf8_string s = {"foo"};` could be your goal. In other words, keep on using e.g. `std::string` as implementation detail and wrap it in a struct. Sprinkle a few overloaded operators on top and you should be able to convert your code step-by-step without too many issues.

Comment: Getting encodings right from diverse sources is a tough job. Though you can represent any encoding well just using UTF8, finally you should stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm onto something, at least as far as C++ strings (`std::string`, `std::basic_string<chat16_t>`) are concerned; there, the key might be to use non-default *character traits*, like so:

```
using ASCII  = char;
using LATIN1 = char;
using UTF8   = char;
using UCS2   = char16_t;
using UTF16  = char16_t;

class ASCIICharTraits  : public std::char_traits<ASCII>  {};
class Latin1CharTraits : public std::char_traits<LATIN1> {};
class UTF8CharTraits   : public std::char_traits<UTF8>   {};
class UCS2CharTraits   : public std::char_traits<UCS2>   {};
class UTF16CharTraits  : public std::char_traits<UTF16>  {};

using ASCIIString  = std::basic_string<ASCII,  ASCIICharTraits>;
using Latin1String = std::basic_string<LATIN1, Latin1CharTraits>;
using UTF8String   = std::basic_string<UTF8,   UTF8CharTraits>;
using UCS2String   = std::basic_string<UCS2,   UCS2CharTraits>;
using UTF16String  = std::basic_string<UTF16,  UTF16CharTraits>;
```

Using distinct types as the `traits` parameter to the `std::basic_string` template ensures that the string types are also treated as distinct types by the compiler, preventing any mixup of incompatibly encoded C++ strings, without having to write a wrapper framework.

Note that for this to work the custom trait types need to be subclassed, not simply aliased. (Theoretically I could write new trait types from scratch, but deriving from `std::char_traits` makes the job much easier, and should make sure I get binary compatibility, allowing to implement trivial conversions (such as from ASCII to Latin-1 or UTF-8) by means of a simple `reinterpret_cast`.

(Fun fact: To the best of my knowledge this mechanism should even work with good old C++03, provided the `using` clauses are replaced with corresponding `typedef`s.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the standard suggestion: sandwich method.

Internally use only one data type (the one of your language or like in this case, of standard libraries).

Only on the layers you will decode (input) or encode (output). There should be clear also why you decide one encoding. Writing to a file? UTF-8 is good (ASCII is a subset, so keep it as UTF-8).  In such part you do also the input validation. Should it be a number? Check that they are unicode numbers. etc.  Data validation and encoding (validation) should be keep nearer as possible as the reading the input. For output take the same rule (but in that case there should be no validation).

So now you may prefix true strings with some prefix (try something unique), and try to find where you encode/decode. Try to move such encoding on outer layers.  When you finished, you remove the prefix.

You may use other prefixes for the other encodings (just temporarily). Also in this case try something unique. Mess with your variable names, not the types.

As alternative, I think you can annotate variables and use external tools to check that some annotations do no mix. Linux kernel uses something like that (e.g. to distinguish user space and kernel pointers). I think it is an overkill for your program.

Why the sandwich? Now you probably know much about UTF-8, UCS-2, UTF-16, etc. But it took time. Next coworker may not know all such details, and so it would cause problems on long terms. We use also integers, without worrying about if it is one-complement, two-complement, or with sign bit, but when we are writing out data. Do the same for strings. Keep the semantic and forget the encoding inside the program. Only the outer layer must handle it.

Comment: You're describing pretty much exactly the general route I already decided to go, except that instead of name prefixes I intended to use strong typing, so that the compiler would help me catch places where encodings get mixed up (I should have mentioned that I presume we do have such issues in the code).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the annotations approach? The whole annotations game is completely new to me.

Comment: @ChristophLipka: No I cannot elaborate. I know very little about it (but I know it exists). There were a lot of discussion about gcc extension licensing. But I never got into it. You may find some documentation in: https://lwn.net/Articles/689907/ I assume it is used also outside Kernel (and I assume it could be used on your case).

Comment: The problem of strong typing: you lose the library functions (so it could be very difficult to implement and to change all calls), or it is not enough strong (so not useful). Maybe you can define a class per type, and just store the string + implement cast functions. All inline, so no performances lost). My prefix is more not to have flag days.

Comment: Judging by a cursory read, the lwn.net article seems irrelevant to my question. It seems to be talking about a C parser library, while I need a solution for C++.

Comment: @ChristophLipka: I think it is irrelevant, because it is too specialist (you may use for huge project, where you can invest on tools). But your question is about types and structures that exists in also in C, so I assume the tools work on generic part of C/C++ of GCC. But I agree, it is not so relevant, but I think it is a project (or clone projects) to look up every few years, to see if it will be improved and used on more generic projects.

Comment: It is my understanding that Sparse is _not_ an extension to GCC, but rather a stand-alone tool, with its own inbuilt C parser. The only connection to GCC seems to be that the basic syntax of Sparse's annotations has been modeled after a corresponding mechanism in GCC, which presumably causes them to be simply ignored when compiling with GCC. Using that same approach in my own project would mean I'd have to write my own stand-alone parser for them, too - which is far more difficult for C++ than for C, and the Sparse project wouldn't be of much use as a starting point.